# How to use Ajax and return view al the same time

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, kohana

I have a login method in my controller where I check if there is such user in database or not. I call this method when press Submit button. I show login from view at the same time.

In my case, it doesn't show message if there is such user. I think because in my controller I load view.

How could I show this message if there is such user using Ajax and if I return view as I do in my case?
I'm using Kohana. Thanks!

My code is:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#submit').on('click', function() {

    if(username.length === 0 || password.length === 0) {
      //...check if validation fails
    }
    else {
      $.ajax({
        url: "/admin/signin" ,
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          "username":username,
          "password":password
        },
        success: function(data) {
          if(data !== 'error') {

            window.location = "/admin/index";
          }
          else
          {
            alert('no such user');
          }
        }
      });
    }

  });

});
```

```html
public function action_signin()
{

if ($_POST) {
$is_admin = Model_Admin::signin($_POST);           

print 'success';
} else {
print 'error';
}
}

$this->template->content = View::factory('admin/login_form');


}
```

Comment: did you managed to find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you want not load 'default' template try using `$this->auto_render = FALSE;`
also kohana controller has method is_ajax `$this->request->is_ajax()`

Answer (score 0):

You controller code will be like this.

```
public function action_signin()
{
    if($this->request->is_ajax()){
        $this->auto_render = FALSE;
    }

    if ($_POST) {
        $is_admin = Model_Admin::signin($_POST);           
        if($is_admin){
            print 'success';
        } else {
           print 'error';
        }
    }else{
    $this->template->content = View::factory('admin/login_form');
    }
}
```